# php data checking and clarification

Tags: php

```
if( isset( $_POST['aquafina'] ) && $_POST['aquafina'] != '' ) 
{
    $message .= "AquafinA: ".( $_POST['aquafina'] ). "\n";
}
```

Noob, questions and clarifications:

This means != (not equal to empty), right?

And

```
if( isset( $_POST['numSelections'] ) && $_POST['numSelections'] > 0 &&

$_POST['numSelections'] < 40 )
```

This means less than 40 for numSelections, right?

Just need some clarification, thank you for not flaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!= ''
```

This is not equal to the empty string, yes. I recommend looking at the [type comparison table.](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

And the second one will mean if numSelections is

- a set variable and
- larger than 0 and
- smaller than 40

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['aquafina'] != ''
means not equal to empty string.

and yes, less than 40, if $_POST['numSelections'] is numeric.